# Java Snake Bug: It happens when change direction quickly

Tags: java

In my Snake code, if the snake is moving LEFT currently, and I then press either UP or DOWN, and then very quickly press RIGHT, the game is over. I knew the reason why it happened, but I don't know how to fix it. Maybe I should announce a new variable for last direction and then compare it with the new direction to decide if the snake should turn to the new direction? I don't know how to fix it. Can somebody help me to solve the problem ? :-)

Here is the relevant code.

```
//Judge the keyboard input
public void changeDirection(Direction newDirection) {
    if (snakeDirection.compatibleWith(newDirection)) {
        snakeDirection = newDirection;
    }
```

Direction.java

```
public enum Direction {

    UP(0),
    RIGHT(1),
    DOWN(2),
    LEFT(3);

    private final int directionCode;

    Direction(int directionCode) {
        this.directionCode = directionCode;
    }

    private int directionCode() {
        return directionCode;
    }

    //
    public boolean compatibleWith(Direction direction) {
        return (this.directionCode() + direction.directionCode()) % 2 == 1;
    }
}
```

GameController.java

```
public class GameController implements Runnable, KeyListener {
    private final Grid grid;
    private final GameView gameView;

    boolean running;

    public GameController(Grid grid, GameView gameView) {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.gameView = gameView;
        this.running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                grid.changeDirection(Direction.UP);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                grid.changeDirection(Direction.DOWN);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                grid.changeDirection(Direction.LEFT);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                grid.changeDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                if (running == false) {
                    grid.init();
                    running = true;
                    new Thread(this).start();
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                if (running) {
                    running = false;
                } else {
                    running = true;
                    new Thread(this).start();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }




    }

    // the Thread
    public void run() {

        while (running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }

            // your code here
            if (grid.nextRound()) {
                gameView.draw();
            } else {

                gameView.showGameOverMessage();
                break;
            }


        }

        running = false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need a new variable. Your `snakeDirection` is the direction you want to use in the next time step and comparing it with `newDirection` only helps when it has been used. You need a `lastUsedDirection` set after a step was done.

### Some comments

You can replace `directionCode` by `ordinal()`.

You should start only a single thread and let it skip the action when `running=false`. Use the constructor allowing to start it with `deamon=true`, so that you can terminate the game without it terminating first. Don't let it terminate. You current code risks having multiple threads running when you press SPACE multiple times fast enough.

Be careful with you variable used in multiple threads. As long as one thread only reads the variable and the other one only writes it, it's enough to use `volatile`. You probably don't even do this and then it can happen that one thread never sees the writes made by another one (this is no theory; this really happens, maybe not in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `x` and `y` positon of the head and the "neck".
What I mean is:

```
  neck
   |
   | xxxx     
   | x      <--- The snake  
  HNxx      
  |           
  |           
 head
```

If the position is the same in one axis, you should not turn.
Here's an actual example (it's C++, but Java has similar syntax, so this shouldn't be a problem).

```
void Snake::setDirection(char dir) {
    switch (direction) {
        case Snake::NORTH:
            if (dir == Snake::SOUTH) return;
            if (body.size() > 1 && body[0]->y == body[1]->y) return;
            break;
        case Snake::SOUTH:
            if (dir == Snake::NORTH) return;
            if (body.size() > 1 && body[0]->y == body[1]->y) return;
            break;
        case Snake::EAST:
            if (dir == Snake::WEST) return;
            if (body.size() > 1 && body[0]->x == body[1]->x) return;
            break;
        case Snake::WEST:
            if (dir == Snake::EAST) return;
            if (body.size() > 1 && body[0]->x == body[1]->x) return;
            break;
    }
    direction = dir;
}
```

`body` is a `std::vector` that holds all the snake segments and `direction` is a `Snake` class variable.